# Configure error when installing FLTK library

Tags: c++, autoconf, msys2, fltk

I'm using Windows with Mingw, installed on path C:\mingw-w64

I installed Msys2 on C:\msys64

Now I want to install FLTK 1.4 following the guidelines from here: https://github.com/fltk/fltk/blob/master/README.Windows.txt

But at the configure command I get this error:

```
$ ./configure
configure: loading site script /etc/config.site
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh ./config.sub
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Edit:
It seems I can run /bin/sh (I don't get any error, but no other message either).
But config.sub doesn't exist...

Comment: _"What should I do?"_ 1st step is check if you can run `/bin/sh` from your command line, if yes, 2nd step is to check what's up with `config.sub` and if you can run that script properly, if it's there check the contents.

Comment: msys2 has fltk: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-fltk](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-fltk) I believe you can install using `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-fltk`

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : it seems I can run /bin/sh (I don't get any error, but no other message either). But config.sub doesn't exist...

Comment: @drescherjm : your idea seems to install fltk-1.3.5-1 and I want to install 1.4 (the latest)

Comment: @Theodore Add that information [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63742465/edit) please. This will help others in giving you a possible way how to solve your problem.